# Is every function with this property an exponential function.

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, functional-equations

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a+b) = f(a)f(b)$ and $f\neq 0$. Can I deduce from this that $f$ is an exponential function i.e. does there exist $0 < c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f = c^{x}$.

These are my ideas so far:
From the definition we get $f(a) = f(a+0) = f(a)f(0)$ for all $a$. Using $f \neq 0$ we get $f(0) = 1$.
We also have $f(n) =f(1+\ldots + 1) = f(1) \cdots f(1) = f(1)^n$ so if $f$ was of the form $f(x) = c^{x}$ then we would need $c = f(1)$ but I don't know if this really is the only option, or if there are functions with this property that are not exponentials.

Comment: Can you obtain the value of $f$ for numbers of the form $1/n$? And then for rationales? After that you may want to see if your function is continuous and use a density argument.

Comment: Yes. If one adds some more conditions. I think Cauchy went this way.

Comment: @FelipePérez Thanks to your tip I understand now that $f$ agrees with $f(1)^x$ on every rational. I also get that if $f$ was continuous, then they have to be equal since they agree on $\mathbb{Q}$ which is a dense subset. But I don't see why $f$ would need to be continuos just from this property.

Comment: Following Felipe's idea you can show it is exponential on rationals. But without an additional assumption such as continuity or monotonicity of $f$, it doesn't follow for all reals -- look up "additive functions" for the similar problem about functions $g$ satisfying $g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y)$.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it is even enough to assume that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable. A proof of this should be in Folland's book "Real Analysis". In general you can use the axiom of choice to construct non-exponential functions satisfying your equation.